# Java : can't get correct input after a loop

Tags: java, input

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception
{
    //intro
    char rt,yn;
    double v1,v2,v3,
        w,        //width
        d,        //depth
        pc,       //pool capacity
        rof= 50,  //rate of flow
        v,        //volume
        ttf,      //time to fill
        cap       //unit capacity
        ;
    int f;

    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);

    System.out.println("Press 'enter' to get started");
    sc.nextLine();

    System.out.println("Please enter the pool type, press 'enter' after you finished");
    do {
        System.out.println("Please enter a alphabet");
        System.out.println("'S'for Small(20x12x4)");
        System.out.println("'L'for Large(30x20x10)");
        System.out.println("'C'for Custom new size");

        //read rt S L C
        rt= (char)System.in.read(); System.in.read();
        while (rt!='S' && rt!='s' && rt!='L' && rt!='l' && rt!='C' && rt!='c')
        {
            System.out.println("invalid input");
            System.out.println("please enter a alphabet");
            sc.next(); 
        }

        if (rt=='S'||rt=='s')
        {
            calc(20,12,4);
        }
        else if(rt=='L'||rt=='l')
        {
            calc(20,12,4);
        }
        else if(rt=='C'||rt=='c')
        {
            System.out.println("Please enter the pool sizes, press enter after each side");
            System.out.println("Please enter Numbers, or errors may occur");
            System.out.println("now please enter your width(in ft)>>");

            v1= sc.nextDouble();  sc.nextLine();
            System.out.println("Please enter your length(in ft)>>");
            v2=sc.nextDouble();  sc.nextLine();
            System.out.println("Please enter your depth(in ft)>>");
            v3=sc.nextDouble(); sc.nextLine();
            calc(v1,v2,v3); 
        }

        yn= (char)System.in.read();
    }
    while(yn=='Y');

    System.out.println("Thank you for using");
}

public static void calc(double l, double w, double d) throws Exception
{
    double 
        pc,      //pool capacity
        rof= 50, //rate of flow
        v,       //volume
        ttf1,    //time to fill, whole num
        cap= 7.5 //unit capacity
        ;

    v = l*w*d;
    pc = v*cap;
    ttf1 = pc /(rof*60);

    System.out.println("It will take "+ ttf1 + " hours to fill up a pool with length: " +
                       l+" ft, width: "+w+" ft, and the depth of"+d+" ft");
    System.in.read();
    System.out.println("want do another one? Y/anykey");
}
```

If i run this, returns invalid input all the time for the second time after typed Y at the end of the first time... what caused this error? is there some ways to avoiding this from happenning?

Comment: I'd recommend making your code look cleaner.

Answer (score 0):

Now it works.

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.Scanner;


public class DataProva {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        //intro
        char rt = 0;
        char yn = 'Y';
        double v1,v2,v3,
            w,        //width
            d,        //depth
            pc,       //pool capacity
            rof= 50,  //rate of flow
            v,        //volume
            ttf,      //time to fill
            cap       //unit capacity
            ;
        int f;

        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);

        System.out.println("Press 'enter' to get started");
        sc.nextLine();
        sc.reset();

        System.out.println("Please enter the pool type, press 'enter' after you finished");
        while(yn=='Y') {
            System.out.println("Please enter a alphabet");
            System.out.println("'S'for Small(20x12x4)");
            System.out.println("'L'for Large(30x20x10)");
            System.out.println("'C'for Custom new size");

            //read rt S L C

            try {
                rt= (char) System.in.read();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            while (rt!='S' && rt!='s' && rt!='L' && rt!='l' && rt!='C' && rt!='c')
            {
                System.out.println("invalid input");
                System.out.println("please enter a alphabet");

               rt=(char) sc.next().charAt(0); 
            }

            if (rt=='S'||rt=='s')
            {
                try {
                    calc(20,12,4);
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
            else if(rt=='L'||rt=='l')
            {
                try {
                    calc(20,12,4);
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
            else if(rt=='C'||rt=='c')
            {
                System.out.println("Please enter the pool sizes, press enter after each side");
                System.out.println("Please enter Numbers, or errors may occur");
                System.out.println("now please enter your width(in ft)>>");

                v1= sc.nextDouble();  sc.nextLine();
                System.out.println("Please enter your length(in ft)>>");
                v2=sc.nextDouble();  sc.nextLine();
                System.out.println("Please enter your depth(in ft)>>");
                v3=sc.nextDouble(); sc.nextLine();
                try {
                    calc(v1,v2,v3);
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                } 
            }
            System.out.println("want do another one? Y/anykey");
            sc.reset();
            try {
                 System.in.read();
                 sc.next();
                yn= (char) System.in.read();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            sc.reset();





        }

        System.out.println("Thank you for using");
        sc.close();

    }

    public static void calc(double l, double w, double d) throws Exception
    {
        double 
            pc,      //pool capacity
            rof= 50, //rate of flow
            v,       //volume
            ttf1,    //time to fill, whole num
            cap= 7.5 //unit capacity
            ;

        v = l*w*d;
        pc = v*cap;
        ttf1 = pc /(rof*60);

        System.out.println("It will take "+ ttf1 + " hours to fill up a pool with length: " +
                           l+" ft, width: "+w+" ft, and the depth of"+d+" ft");


    }


}
```

You had a problem where System.in read a /r. A return charachter caused by pressing Return.
In your first while check you had not assigned sc.next() to rt so it just loop endlessly. Because rt was always the same as before.

As a general rule, main shouldn't throw Exception, because there is no one that can manage that Exception. You should manage Exception with try catch in the main.

Your variables should be initialized everytime.

You code is very Procedural, you could do something better thinking with object.

If u use Wrapper class it is better ( wrapper class for char are Charachter).

Comment: That helps a lot, im still a newbie to java, thankyou so much

Comment: @user3642243 Well, as a hint,
You can think of a pool like an OBJECT pool with his attributes.
and build an object with Pool pool = new Pool(attributes)
then operate with it.
Anyway If u are satisfied accept my answer :)